# Wiring up a ceiling fan

Tags: wiring, fans

I have a Mitsubishi ceiling fan of this type:

[image]

[image]

The given wiring diagram (pasted inside the cover of the remote switch box) is as follows:

[image]

This is a 230V region, and the usual wiring color code is brown=live, blue=neutral, and green/yellow=earth.

I can't reconcile the wiring diagram with what I see inside the remote switch box:

Front:
[image]

Back:
[image]

This is a brand new unit taken out of its box, after many years of forgotten storage.

I see only two connection points in the remote switch box (A and B), but the wiring diagram says three (P, Q and R). Q looks like A, and P looks like B. But where is R?

Any suggestions on how this fan should be wired?

Comment: Everything that wiring diagram shows you is already done for you inside the speed-control switch. Put Live on B and Neutral on A and you're done.

Comment: Yes, but how about the wiring from fan to speed-control switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can assume the wiring diagram uses American wire colors (white = neutral), then you should wire-up the switch box like this:

- Blue from the fan goes to the middle terminal (which you marked as A)
- Brown from the fan goes to the free terminal
- Blue from the net goes to terminal B
- Brown from the net goes to the same terminal as brown from the fan.

If we can't assume a meaning for the wire colors, I would swap blue and brown in the description above (putting the switch in the hot side).